# onMetaData never called for MP3 streaming

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am streaming a MP3 resource using NetStream in Flash.

To display the progress of the song I need the **duration** of the song.

But **onMetaData** is never being called for the NetStream object.

Here's the code http://pastebin.com/VZvdqTF5

**Update:** seems like the MP3 resource does not provide necessary MetaData for the MP3 resource. So this is not the problem with the code, it has something to do with the streaming server I am using in the application.

Comment: Post some code.. We're not magicians! :)

Comment: for onMetadata to be called the mp3 needs to have metadata which is not always the case. You can find out the duration of the mp3 once it's completely loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you are setting the [client](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#client) propriety of the [NetStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html) class.

> **client property**: Specifies the object on which callback methods are invoked to handle
>   streaming or F4V/FLV file data. The default object is this, the
>   NetStream object being created. If you set the client property to
>   another object, callback methods are invoked on that other object. The
>   NetStream.client object can call the following functions and receive
>   an associated data object: onCuePoint(), onImageData(), onMetaData(),
>   onPlayStatus(), onSeekPoint(), onTextData(), and onXMPData().

```
yourNetStreamInstance.client = {onMetaData:onMetaData}; 

function onMetaData(metaData:Object):void
{
    trace(metaData.duration); // duration
}
```

Comment: I do set **client** property for my **NetStream** object like this   `myNetStream.client = this;`

Also I define the **onMetaData** function.

Comment: So, probably it would help if you add your code. I just implemented this feature as well and worked without issues. Maybe there is something else that is missing.

Comment: Just try to replace this line in your code: `netStream.client = this;` to this: `netStream.client = {onMetaData:onMetaData};` as I listed on my answer.

Comment: @ManmohanBishnoi Check if the function is reached at all, and check if your netstream source actually provides metadata for the function to receive.

Comment: @Vesper you were right, the NetStream source does not provide MetaData at all. `m_metaData = null`

Answer (score 0):

```
ns.client = new ConnectionClient(this);
```

Define that class inside of your NetStream class at the bottom

```
class ConnectionClient {
    private var _owner:YourNSStreamObjectClass;

    public function ConnectionClient(owner:YourNSStreamObjectClass) : void {
        _owner = owner;
    }

    public function onMetaData(info : Object) : void {
        //_owner.setMetaData(info);

    }

    public function onCuePoint(info : Object) : void {
        //trace("cuepoint: time=" + info.time + " name=" + info.name + " type=" + info.type);
    }

    public function onXMPData(info : Object) : void {
        //trace("xmp data = " + info);
    }

    public function onPlayStatus(info : Object) : void {
        //trace("onPlayStatus data = " + info);
    }
}
```